# Xampp + IIS working together on the same server

Tags: apache, iis

I have one server with 2 ip addresses.

I have multiples applications in .net (webapi, a console application, etc) and one specific using PHP which is running on apache (w/ xampp).

I configured IIS to run on default port 80 and xampp is using port 8080.

As I said before, I have two ip addresses and two domains (eg: domain1.com and domain2.com).

I need to pinpoint domain1.com.br to the IIS app (which is working) but my php app never get reached since all the requests are directed to port 80 (which iis takes control).

1. What can I do to solve this?
2. I know that I can point both ip's to port 80 but how to tell IIS whenever he gets a request from a specific domain/host (in this case, domain2.com.br) he redirects to the port 8080?

Comment: Nobody? Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954874/iis-binds-to-all-ip-addresses-on-a-server-when-you-install-iis-7-0-on and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html ? Note that there is a https://serverfault.com/ (also belonging to the StackExchange familiy) where you may get more attention to this question, or perhaps find already existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to let the apache takes the control,due to apache's redirect features.The main idea is to setup the apache, use apache's redirect features(vhost,if you prefer to call it so) to direct the special requests to your IIS server.

1. Change your IIS listening to port 8080 (and set the domain to your domain,domain1.com for example).Leave your apache to listen on 80.
2. Enable the module below in your apache config file(http.conf):

   `LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`

   `LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so`

   `LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so`

   `LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so`

And Enable:

```
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

3. The next step is to setup the virtual host. Edit the config file`conf\ extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "x:\The\Dir\to\Your\Php\Site"
    ServerName domain2.com.br   
    ErrorLog "logs/domain2-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain2-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And the setup to your domain2.com.br is Done.Restart your apache server,visit your site by domain name ,and your php site shall be working.

4. If the steps upon is working as expected,this shall be the last step.

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName your.net.site.domain.com
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
       ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
       ErrorLog "logs/domain1-error.log"
       CustomLog "logs/domain1-access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

And now it should work as you expect it to.

Comment: It didn't work... I just gave up and started using PHP on iis.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Reverse Proxy method

What is **Reverse Proxy Method**

- A reverse proxy server is a type of proxy server that typically sits
  behind the firewall in a private network and directs client requests
  to the appropriate backend server. A reverse proxy provides an
  additional level of abstraction and control to ensure the smooth flow
  of network traffic between clients and servers.

Refer [NGINX Documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) to know more about Reverse Proxy.

You can use reverse proxy either on your **IIS** or **Apache**(Xampp) Server. But since you have a Windows Server I recommend you to do reverse proxy on IIS server.

**Example:** [Rewrite or Reverse proxy in IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/)